# batch file makes another batch file which make another file

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd

I want write a batch file which makes another batch file which make a file.

I wrote something like this.

```
echo:IF EXIST %%ALLUSERSPROFILE%%\Pulpit (SET AutoStart="%%ALLUSERSPROFILE%%\Menu Start\Programy\Autostart\go2.bat" )> %Esc_LinkTarget%\GO.BAT
echo:IF EXIST %%ALLUSERSPROFILE%%\Desktop  (SET AutoStart="%%ALLUSERSPROFILE%%\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\Startup\go2.bat" ) >> %Esc_LinkTarget%\GO.BAT
echo:ECHO:REM DEKLARACJA LITERY MAPOWANEGO DYSKU ^> %%AutoStart%% >> %Esc_LinkTarget%\GO.BAT
echo:ECHO:SET MapLetter=T: ^>^> %%AutoStart%% >> %Esc_LinkTarget%\GO.BAT
echo:ECHO:NET USE %%%%MapLetter%%%%\\%COMPUTERNAME%\%LinkName% ^>^> %%AutoStart%% >>%Esc_LinkTarget%\GO.BAT
echo:ECHO:echo:IF EXIST %%%%ALLUSERSPROFILE%%%%\Pulpit (SET Esc_LinkDest=%%%%ALLUSERSPROFILE%%%%\Pulpit\ ) %%>>%% %%AutoStart%% >>%Esc_LinkTarget%\GO.BAT
echo:ECHO:echo:IF EXIST %%%%ALLUSERSPROFILE%%%%\Desktop  (SET Esc_LinkDest=%%%%ALLUSERSPROFILE%%%%\Desktop\ ) ^>^> %%AutoStart%% >>%Esc_LinkTarget%\GO.BAT
echo:ECHO:echo:IF EXIST %%%%ALLUSERSPROFILE%%%%\Pulpit\%LinkName%.lnk GOTO DLP1 ^>^> %%AutoStart%% >>%Esc_LinkTarget%\GO.BAT
echo:ECHO:echo:IF EXIST %%%%ALLUSERSPROFILE%%%%\Desktop\%LinkName%.lnk GOTO DLP1 ^>^> %%AutoStart%% >>%Esc_LinkTarget%\GO.BAT
echo:echo:echo Set oWS = WScript.CreateObject("WScript.Shell") ^^> tmp.vbs ^>^> %%AutoStart%% >>%Esc_LinkTarget%\GO.BAT
echo:echo:echo sLinkFile = "%%%%Esc_LinkDest%%%%%LinkName%.lnk" ^^>^^> tmp.vbs ^>^> %%AutoStart%% >>%Esc_LinkTarget%\GO.BAT
echo:echo:echo Set oLink = oWS.CreateShortcut(sLinkFile) ^^>^^> tmp.vbs ^>^> %%AutoStart%% >>%Esc_LinkTarget%\GO.BAT
echo:echo:echo oLink.TargetPath = "%%%%MapLetter%%%%\" ^^>^^> tmp.vbs ^>^>%%AutoStart%% >> %Esc_LinkTarget%\GO.BAT
echo:echo:echo oLink.Save ^^>^^> tmp.vbs ^>^> %%AutoStart%% >>%Esc_LinkTarget%\GO.BAT
echo:echo:cscript //nologo .\tmp.vbs 6^>^^> %%AutoStart%% >>%Esc_LinkTarget%\GO.BAT
echo:echo:del .\tmp.vbs >^^^^> %%AutoStart%% >>%Esc_LinkTarget%\GO.BAT
echo:echo:^:DLP1 ^>^> %%AutoStart%% >>%Esc_LinkTarget%\GO.BAT
```

... and I want that go.bat to have something like this...

```
IF EXIST %%ALLUSERSPROFILE%%\Pulpit (SET AutoStart="%%ALLUSERSPROFILE%%\Menu Start\Programy\Autostart\go2.bat" )
IF EXIST %%ALLUSERSPROFILE%%\Desktop  (SET AutoStart="%%ALLUSERSPROFILE%%\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\Startup\go2.bat" )
ECHO:REM DEKLARACJA LITERY MAPOWANEGO DYSKU > %%AutoStart%%
ECHO:SET MapLetter=T: >> %%AutoStart%%
ECHO:NET USE %%%%MapLetter%%%%\\%COMPUTERNAME%\%LinkName% >> %%AutoStart%%
echo:IF EXIST %%%%ALLUSERSPROFILE%%%%\Pulpit (SET Esc_LinkDest=%%%%ALLUSERSPROFILE%%%%\Pulpit\ ) >> %%AutoStart%%
echo:IF EXIST %%%%ALLUSERSPROFILE%%%%\Desktop  (SET Esc_LinkDest=%%ALLUSERSPROFILE%%\Desktop\ ) >> %%AutoStart%%
echo:IF EXIST %%ALLUSERSPROFILE%%\Pulpit\%LinkName%.lnk GOTO DLP1 >> %%AutoStart%%
echo:IF EXIST %%ALLUSERSPROFILE%%\Desktop\%LinkName%.lnk GOTO DLP1 >> %%AutoStart%%
echo:echo Set oWS = WScript.CreateObject("WScript.Shell") ^>^> tmp.vbs >> %%AutoStart%%
echo:echo sLinkFile = "%%Esc_LinkDest%%%%LinkName%%.lnk" ^>^> tmp.vbs >> %%AutoStart%%
echo:echo Set oLink = oWS.CreateShortcut(sLinkFile) ^>^> tmp.vbs >> %%AutoStart%%
echo:echo oLink.TargetPath = "%%MapLetter%%\" ^>^> tmp.vbs >> %%AutoStart%%
echo:echo oLink.Save ^>^> tmp.vbs >> %%AutoStart%%
echo:cscript //nologo .\tmp.vbs >> %%AutoStart%%
echo:del .\tmp.vbs >> %%AutoStart%%
echo:^:DLP1 >> %AutoStart%
```

and go2.bat have this:

```
ECHO:REM DEKLARACJA LITERY MAPOWANEGO DYSKU
SET MapLetter=T:
NET USE %MapLetter%\\%COMPUTERNAME%\%LinkName%
IF EXIST %ALLUSERSPROFILE%\Pulpit (SET Esc_LinkDest=%ALLUSERSPROFILE%\Pulpit\ )
IF EXIST %ALLUSERSPROFILE%\Desktop  (SET Esc_LinkDest=%ALLUSERSPROFILE%\Desktop\ )
IF EXIST %ALLUSERSPROFILE%\Pulpit\%LinkName%.lnk GOTO DLP1
IF EXIST %ALLUSERSPROFILE%\Desktop\%LinkName%.lnk GOTO DLP1
echo Set oWS = WScript.CreateObject("WScript.Shell") >> tmp.vbs
echo sLinkFile = "%Esc_LinkDest%%LinkName%.lnk" >> tmp.vbs
echo Set oLink = oWS.CreateShortcut(sLinkFile) >> tmp.vbs
echo oLink.TargetPath = "%%MapLetter%%\" >> tmp.vbs
echo oLink.Save >> tmp.vbs
cscript //nologo .\tmp.vbs
del .\tmp.vbs
:DLP1
```

Can you help me with this? I don't know how to write the first one that creates go2.bat

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can easily do such conversion in Notepad++ or using any other utility allowing for search and replace using regex. You just have to search and replace the following:

```
replace "^" with "echo "
replace "\^" with "\^\^"
replace ">" with "^>"
replace "%" with "%%"
replace "$" with " >> go2.bat"
```

(Order of replacements is important.)

There is much more characters that need escaping in such operations, but in the case of go2.bat only `>` and `%` needed it. You should consult http://www.robvanderwoude.com/escapechars.php and try writing appropriate regexes.

Also, I would advise you to add a line at the start of the script to delete `go2.bat` if it already exist. Or you can manually change first `>>` to `>` so existing `go2.bat` will be always truncated.

**UPDATE:**

Using only above replacement rules I've created for you sample batch script which creates other batch script with creates another batch script. I've used above rules **twice** - first to create generator for the last script and then to create generator of the generator. Here, check:

```
echo echo ECHO:REM DEKLARACJA LITERY MAPOWANEGO DYSKU ^> drugi.bat > pierwszy.bat
echo echo SET MapLetter=T: ^>^> drugi.bat >> pierwszy.bat
echo echo NET USE %%%%MapLetter%%%%\\%%%%COMPUTERNAME%%%%\%%%%LinkName%%%% ^>^> drugi.bat >> pierwszy.bat
echo echo IF EXIST %%%%ALLUSERSPROFILE%%%%\Pulpit (SET Esc_LinkDest=%%%%ALLUSERSPROFILE%%%%\Pulpit\ ) ^>^> drugi.bat >> pierwszy.bat
echo echo IF EXIST %%%%ALLUSERSPROFILE%%%%\Desktop  (SET Esc_LinkDest=%%%%ALLUSERSPROFILE%%%%\Desktop\ ) ^>^> drugi.bat >> pierwszy.bat
echo echo IF EXIST %%%%ALLUSERSPROFILE%%%%\Pulpit\%%%%LinkName%%%%.lnk GOTO DLP1 ^>^> drugi.bat >> pierwszy.bat
echo echo IF EXIST %%%%ALLUSERSPROFILE%%%%\Desktop\%%%%LinkName%%%%.lnk GOTO DLP1 ^>^> drugi.bat >> pierwszy.bat
echo echo echo Set oWS = WScript.CreateObject("WScript.Shell") ^^^>^^^> tmp.vbs ^>^> drugi.bat >> pierwszy.bat
echo echo echo sLinkFile = "%%%%Esc_LinkDest%%%%%%%%LinkName%%%%.lnk" ^^^>^^^> tmp.vbs ^>^> drugi.bat >> pierwszy.bat
echo echo echo Set oLink = oWS.CreateShortcut(sLinkFile) ^^^>^^^> tmp.vbs ^>^> drugi.bat >> pierwszy.bat
echo echo echo oLink.TargetPath = "%%%%%%%%MapLetter%%%%%%%%\" ^^^>^^^> tmp.vbs ^>^> drugi.bat >> pierwszy.bat
echo echo echo oLink.Save ^^^>^^^> tmp.vbs ^>^> drugi.bat >> pierwszy.bat
echo echo cscript //nologo .\tmp.vbs ^>^> drugi.bat >> pierwszy.bat
echo echo del .\tmp.vbs ^>^> drugi.bat >> pierwszy.bat
echo echo :DLP1 ^>^> drugi.bat >> pierwszy.bat
```

Comment: Mogę Cię prosić żebyś przerobił mi jedną linijkę kodu tak bym miał przykład do przerobienia reszty. Na taką która znajdowała by się w pierszym pilku, tworzyła drugi pliki który stworzy trzeci. Ze zeminnymi sobie poradzę problem sprawiją mi strumienie.

Comment: @user3569199, zaktualizowałem moją odpowiedź o przykład skryptu generującego plik `pierwszy.bat` a później `drugi.bat`, który odpowiada Twojemu plikowi `go2.bat`. Nie wiem jak skomplikowane te skrypty chcesz "opakowywać" i generować innymi skryptami, ale da się to wszystko robić wyrażeniami regularnymi, chociaż w niektórych przypadkach może to się robić skomplikowane. W treści mojej odpowiedzi podałem link do strony internetowej z "escape characters".

Comment: Btw, zaktualizowałem moją wypowiedź nie tylko po napise "UPDATE", ale także i przed, więc polecam przeczytać całość mojej wypowiedzi.

Answer (score 1):

if you prefer a solution without worrying about escaping chars:

```
@echo off
rem go.bat
echo hello, this is file nr. 1
echo it will create file nr. 2
for /f "delims=:" %%i in ('findstr /n /b "::DATA1" "%~df0"') do set datastart=%%i
more +%datastart% "%~df0" >go1.bat
set a=alpha
set b=beta
echo starting go1.bat:
call go1.bat
echo back to the root.
echo %a%,%b%,%c%,%ab%,%bc%
exit /b

::DATA1
rem go1.bat
echo    hello, this is file nr. 2
echo    it will create file nr. 3 
for /f "delims=:" %%i in ('findstr /n /b "::DATA2" "%~df0"') do set datastart=%%i
more +%datastart% "%~df0" >go2.bat
set c=gamma
set ab=%a%%b%
echo    starting go2.bat
call go2.bat
echo    back to level 1
echo    doing something more
echo    %a%,%b%,%c%,%ab%,%bc%
exit /b

::DATA2
rem go2.bat
echo        hello, this is file nr. 3
echo        I will do something.
set bc=%b%%c%
echo        %a%,%b%,%c%,%ab%,%bc%
exit /b
```